# MongoDB Indexing a field which may not exist

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection which has an optional field `xy_id`. About 10% of the documents (out of 500k) does not have this `xy_id` field.

I have quite a lot of queries to this collection like `find({xy_id: <id>})`.

I tried indexing it normally (`.createIndex({xy_id: 1}, {"background": true})`) and it does improve the query speed.

Is this the correct way to index the field in this case? or should I be using a sparse index or another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct way. The default behaviour of MongoDB is serving well in this case. You can see in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#options-for-all-index-types) that index creation supports an `unique` flag, which is `false` by default. All your documents missing the index key will be indexed under a single index entry. Queries can use this index in all cases because all the documents are indexed.

On the other hand, if you use sparse index the documents missing the index key will not be indexed at all. Some operations such as count, sort and other queries will not be able to use the sparse index unless explicitly hinted to do so. If explicitly hinted, you should be okay with incorrect results - the entries not in the index will be omitted in the result. You can read about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/#sparse-index-and-incomplete-results).